# Exporting function in ES6 / react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

On the server side (nodejs/express), I have no problems in exporting and referencing this file (using Attempt1).

```
// collectionFile.js
function collection() {
    let data = {};
    function getData(key) {
        return data[key];
    }
    function setData(key, value) {
        data[key] = value;
    }
    return {
        getData: getData,
        setData: setData
    };
}

const instanceOfCollection = collection();
```

On the client side (React), I'm just not able to reference and access the getData function. Below are some of the combination I tried. None of them work. How can I make it work ?

```
// Attempt1: export
// module.exports.getter = instanceOfCollection.getData;

// Attempt1: import
// const getter = require('./collectionFile').getter;
// Uncaught TypeError: getter is not a function

// Attempt2: export
// export default { instanceOfCollection };

// Attempt2: import
// import instanceOfCollection from './collectionFile';
// const instance = instanceOfCollection.getData;
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

// Attempt3: export
// export const instanceOfCollection = collection();

// Attempt3: import
// import { instanceOfCollection } from './collectionFile';
// const instance = instanceOfCollection.getData;
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
```

Edit: Turns out that I was referencing File A from File B and also File B from File A earlier

Comment: Could you include your file structure?

Comment: Are you using and module bundler or is it just several javascript files?

Comment: There are just 2 files in the same folder. I'm importing the collectionFile.js from the other file. Note that I don't have any problem exporting constants

Comment: Just several js files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do such things:

1. *ES5 export*

   `module.export = instanceOfCollection`

   then

   `var getData = require('my_module').getData`
2. *ES6 export*

   `export default instanceOfCollection`

   then

   `import { getData, setData } from 'my_module'`
3. *ES6 named export*

   `export const setter = instanceOfCollection.setData
    export const getter = instanceOfCollection.getData`

   then

   `import { setter, getter } from 'my_module'`

   or

   `import * as myCollection from 'my_module'
    myCollection.getter()
    myCollection.setter()`
4. *ES5 with renaming*

   `module.export = {
     getter: instanceOfCollection.getData,
     setter: instanceOfCollection.setData,
    }`

   then

   `const { setter, getter } = require('my_module')`

   or

   `const getter = require('my_module').getter
    const setter = require('my_module').setter`

Hope some of them will work for you.

Comment: `import { getData, setData } from 'my_module'` doesn't work. I'm trying the others.

Comment: @KayaToast Do you see how i'm exporting it? Without curly brackets!

Comment: Yes, I was careful about the braces. I have tried them all. None of them work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @KayaToast I'm not sure what you are doing, but i'm testing it right now on my machine and it works well.

Comment: Your last method works when I try to reference from a different file. Turns out that I was referencing File A from File B and also File B from File A earlier.